# how to map a dapper row with a .net object having a different (nested) structure

Tags: dapper

I'm looking for a way to map a row of the following table with the following object :

```
create table Foo (
  Id   BIGINT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  A int,
  ACertainty  float,
  B string,
  BCertainty float
  ....
)

public class FuzzyValue<T>{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public double Certainty { get; private set; }
}

class Foo {
  public FuzzyValue<int> A { get; set;}
  public FuzzyValue<string> B { get; set;}
  ...
}
```

Obviously, I can have dapper return a dynamic and do the mapping manually, but this manual tedious work kind of defeats the purpose of dapper, doesn't it?

Is there an easy way to have dapper do the mapping automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a not so trivial mapper to do this.

If someone needs it, the source is [here](https://github.com/BrannJoly/NestedMapper) and there's a nuget package available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NestedMapper/)